# Random number generation with Poisson distribution in C#

Tags: c#

I'm using `MathNet.Numerics.Distributions` to use Poisson distribution.

I need to generate random numbers using Poisson. here is a sample code:

```
 var d = new Poisson(0.3);
 d.Sample();
```

I need to set a range for it. for example, generating random numbers between 1 to 100. any idea?

Comment: @ericlippert has a whole series on random generators, distributions and probabilities on his blog at ericlippert.com

Comment: The simplest method should be to check the value, and just generate a new one if it falls outside the range. And if the the probability of this is low, it will have a low performance impact. But for a distribution with λ = 0.3 you probably want to start at zero.